# Potential and possible damage of executed Windows Applications through Wine environment in Linux?

Tags: wine, antivirus

Related to this recent Question: [Can a Windows virus transfer to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441458/can-a-windows-virus-transfer-to-ubuntu) and JFA's comment,  which is not only an interesting, but also a valid one:

> Can you also get a Windows virus by running an infected .exe in Wine?

I was wondering the same. Also, how great is the possibility of potential damage, due to execution of malicious code within the executable, while running under Wine? (I guess that most Linux users who also use wine and alike don't use antivirus protection, but still come across this problem, unnoticed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doesn't address the full scope but could be helpful to have in mind.

Anti-virus software are useful to *analyze* files. For instance, under GNU/Linux you can use it *previous* execution of the executable file.

For this task there are several websites that analyze local and online files and one of the most popular desktop software is [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/).

Comment: This does not answer my question. Please read again more carefully. Anyway [+1] for your effort and extended information that may be useful to others though.